# scroll view issue Android

Tags: java, android

I am adding layouts programmatically.I have added a scrollview as a parent layout and a combination of horizontal and vertical linearlayouts when I add a list view in the scrollview I am getting an issue that my UI is not taking full screen although the listview height is set to fill parent .There is a blank space added at the bottom and the height of the listview gets very small .I haven't find the reason why it's happening, is it a bug in android for scrollview ?

Answer (score 1):

`fill_parent` won't work.  Try setting `android:fillViewport="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code, I'd have to take a guess and say that your ScrollView is not set to fill_parent.

Try using layout editor in Eclipse or the hierachyviewer that ships with the Android SDK to examine your layout in the emulator and see which view is not filling the screen.